# Why doesn´t docker-compose env_file work but environment does?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

When I am using env_file in docker-compose.yml it builds correctly, but when I am trying to use docker-compose my node app can´t find env_file variables inside the process.env object.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
node1:
container_name: node01
env_file: ./env/node1.production.env
#environment:
  #- SOME_VALUE=9599
build:
  context: ./node1
  dockerfile: dockerfile
ports:
  - "3000:3000"  
networks:
  - dev_net
```

Here is my node1.production.env file:

```
SOME_VALUE=9599
```

When I use environment instead, my node app works fine:

**DOCKER Version :** 17.03 
**DOCKER COMPOSE Version :** 1.14 
**OS :** CentOS

Comment: Hi Mohamed, welcome to SO. Thanks for the question. Please take a moment to look into this page and see how to format properly (so that others can help you more easily): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you able to generalize this a bit more so someone can reproduce? We don't have your code or `Dockerfile` to reproduce. Maybe you can try https://gist.github.com/andyshinn/3034fa88e679e6357294e7a9b16b8197 as a start and see that it works properly? This is my example which works fine.

Comment: i tried to chage the name of node1.production.env to otherName.production.env and it works , seems i've already exported variable with that name, now i am trying to dynamically change .production to .stage or .test to be some thing like node_app.stage.env... do you how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **should** work. I guess that you might have defined variables more than once in `node1.production.env` file. Verify if the env file is correct.

From the code you gave, it seems there are no errors in the syntax you are using, and if there were, they would have been reported before build could even be started. In my case, I use env file as follows:

```
env_file:
  - .env
```

where `.env` named file is present in the base directory.